# Google search and multilanguage PHP dynamically translated website without page duplicates?

Tags: php, redirect, dynamic, multilingual

I have a simple website with few pages. I use a dropdown list with languages which uses PHP function to translate whole page into a desired language and saves a language preference in a cookie.
This works fine, but because of this my page only shows up in English on Google search. I want it to also show in other languages.

I have checked Google devs website and it seems my way is not recommended by Google:
https://developers.google.com/search/docs/specialty/international/managing-multi-regional-sites

Instead, they recommend using subdomains or URL part like `/**en**/index.php`.

The problem is, I do not want to have my website copied many times in subfolders like /es/index.php, /fr/index.php etc. because every little change on one of my pages, would make me change it also in all these language variations PHP files.

So, the question is how can I have one index.php page with all my translations in database (or seperate php files), so that i do not need to maintain duplicate copies for language variations of my website, and yet allow Google to understand that my site is in other languages so that users searching in these languages can find it?

I have seen a solution which uses tags:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://example.com/page">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="https://example.com/es/page">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="https://example.com/fr/page">
```

but as I said, i do not want to have duplicate pages in seperate folders, i only want to have one page translated dynamically, so that I can easily add new languages, and if I need to add something, i only need to do it once, instead of changing it on all other language variation php pages.

Comment: I'm suggesting you to look for a PHP router which supports parameters. Look this one https://github.com/mrjgreen/phroute which supports up to PHP 8.1

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried but do not understand it well :( What is it for and how should I use it?
I think i understood one part, for example this can help me to take one part of the URL so that my PHP can use it as a variable, but it does not help in my problem.

for example, how can i let google now that my website has /es/index.php spanish site? Even if Google knows it, if someone enters it, they would see 404 error because i do not have a "es" directory with "index.php" file.

Comment: You're not supposed to "have" a physically existing directory `es` - the _router_ is what is supposed to take care of this.

Comment: _"for example, how can i let google now that my website has /es/index.php spanish site?"_ - your dropdown that up until now set the cookie and reloaded the page(?), should simply contains links instead now. So if you are on `/en/foobar`, you would link to `/es/foobar` and `/fr/foobar` on that page ... and then you simply let Google find that link, same as it would any other ...